# How to prepare data for TpyTorch's 3d attn_mask argument in MultiHeadAttention

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

I'm currently trying to implement an Encoder-Decoder architecture for text summarization based on Transformers. Thus I need ti apply MultiHeadAttention on the Decoder site of the model. Since I want to ensure that the model doesn't attend to unseen tokens of the target sequence, I need to use the 3D attention mask (`attn_mask`) argument.

According to the documentation (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html), the shape of the mask must be `BATCH_SIZE * NUMBER_HEADS, SEQUENCE_LENGTH, SEQUENCE_LENGTH`. Which is fine, as it provides the possibility to use different attentions between the Heads, which I don't need in my case ...

But the documentation doesn't state how the tensor needs to be filled regarding it's first dimension and I can't see/ find it in the implementation how it is actually used...

Is it:

```
[
  [2D Attention for Batch 1 for Head 1]
  [2D Attention for Batch 2 for Head 1]
  ...
  [2D Attention for Batch 1 for Head 2]
  [2D Attention for Batch 2 for Head 2]
  ...
  [2D Attention for Batch n for Head n]
]
```

or

```
[
  [2D Attention for Batch 1 for Head 1]
  [2D Attention for Batch 1 for Head 2]
  ...
  [2D Attention for Batch 2 for Head 1]
  [2D Attention for Batch 2 for Head 2]
  ...
  [2D Attention for Batch n for Head n]
]
```

Would be great if someone knows :)

Comment: Analyzing the unit tests of PyTorch it looks like Option 2) is correct, as in the Unit tests they are using `torch.repeat_interleave` instead of `torch.repeat` (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c74c0c571880df886474be297c556562e95c00e0/test/test_nn.py#L5039)

Comment: Yep, `repeat_interleave` seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same query until I get to the [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c74c0c571880df886474be297c556562e95c00e0/test/test_nn.py#L5039) posted by [cokeSchlimpf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4042936/cokeschlumpf). Thanks for sharing this.

##### Overview:

If we want to set different `mask = src_mask` for each of the example/instance in a batch, then it's advised ([here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.forward)) to have the `src_attention_mask` in shape of `N.num_heads, T, S` where `N` is the batch-size, `num_heads` is the number of heads in `MultiHeadAttention` module. Additionally, `T` is the target sequence length and `S` is the source sequence length.

###### Explanation of code at [link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c74c0c571880df886474be297c556562e95c00e0/test/test_nn.py#L5039):

Say, `mask` is of shape `N, T, S`, then with `torch.repeat_interleave(mask, num_heads, dim=0)` each mask instance (in total there are `N` instances) is repeated `num_heads` times and stacked to form `num_heads, T, S` shape array. Repeating this for all such `N` masks we'll finally get an array of shape:

```
[
    [num_heads, T, S] # for example 1 in the batch
    [num_heads, T, S] # for example 2 in the batch
    .
    .
    .
    [num_heads, T, S] # for example N in the batch
] = [N.num_heads, T, S] # after concatenating along dim=0
```

The following is small snippet of code on implementation (with `torch==1.12.1+cu102`).

```py
import torch

class test(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(test, self).__init__()
        enc_layer = torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=16, nhead=8, batch_first=True)
        self.layer = torch.nn.TransformerEncoder(enc_layer, num_layers=1)

    def forward(self, x, src_mask, key_mask):
        return self.layer(x, mask=src_mask, src_key_padding_mask=key_mask)

mod = test()
mod.eval()
out = mod(x=torch.randn(2, 22, 16), src_mask=torch.ones(8*2, 22, 22), key_mask=torch.ones(2, 22))
print(out.shape)
```

*Hope this helps!*